# How can I bulk load data in redis timeseries DB?

Tags: redis, time-series, redistimeseries

I was trying to insert 1M entries in redis timeseries DB (on my local machine).
For this, I was using add(sourceKey, timestamp, value) method of RedisTimeSeries on every entry.

Wanted to know if there's a better way to do this and if bulk load is possible in redis timeseries.

Couldn't find a method for bulk loading of data in this doc:
https://oss.redis.com/redistimeseries/commands/#tsadd

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the fastest way is to combine pipelining and the `TS.MADD` command

- https://redis.io/topics/pipelining
- https://oss.redis.com/redistimeseries/commands/#tsmadd

Comment: thanks for the response. Do this process work with the redistimeseries module: https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert